# text field width issue on different O.S

Tags: html, linux, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have coded a text field with a button of `width="90%".`The problem is that it displays correctly in Chrome for Windows, but displays wider in the Linux version of Chrome. The height of the text field is also shorter by one pixel in the Linux version.

The css code:

```
#search-fld {
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0;
 -ms-border-radius: 0;
 -o-border-radius: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-color: #D6D6D6;
 width: 90%;//the width appear to be longer in the linux version
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 height: 24px;//the height appear to be less one pixel in the linux version
 }
```

I'm using bootstrap.

Please advise...

Windows: [image: Windows Screen Shot]

Linux: [image: Linux Screen Shot]

Comment: just side note; you dont need to put those border radius 0 is default

Comment: no because as I stated, i'm using bootstrap, and because of that there is a radius for the text field

Comment: It wouldn't have to do with the different fonts?

Comment: I don't think the font type would cause that